# Highcharts Bubblechart min/max bubble size

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I want to display some dynamic data on a bubblechart. At the moment, when points are added or taken away, highcharts is recalculating the size of the remaining bubbles. Is there a way to specify the min/max like there is on the x and y axis ?

I have seen a minSize and maxSize option in the source code, but I think these specify pixels, not a min max value for the data.

Comment: Highcharts won't modify your values - if you want to set min/max values you have to preprocess your data accordingly and then update points or set new data. As you said, you still can use minSize and maxSize as pixels or percent values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highcharts calculates the size of the bubbles like this:

largest bubble radius = maxSize
smallest bubble radius= minSize

So if you add a bubble with a lower z value  then the smallest bubble, the new bubble will get radius minSize. The bubble that used to be the smallest bubble will grow.
The same goes for a new bubble that is larger then the largest bubble.

If you know the possible range of z values, you could calculate minSize  based on the distance of the smallest z-value to the start of that range and maxSize on the distance of the largest z-value to the end of that range.
Now if you add a bubble that is smaller that the smallest bubble, you adjust minSize. The existing bubbles will keep their previous size.

Comment: Today I noticed that using percentage in minSize can make bubbles disappear! see http://jsfiddle.net/kzoon/GE9zz/
So, that won't help....